# PHP and JS - How to get value from chosen checkbox is checked and enter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just want to create dynamic value will be sent to alert popup according how much checkbox has checked.

1- This mean when checkbox Test 1 is **checked** and **press enter** button,just alert value = "1"

2- When **checked** Test 1, Test 2 and 3  and **press enter**,give values = "1,2,3" and same way etc.

3- Then,if **checked all** of checkbox and **press enter** it will give all values = "1,2,3,4"

This the function I have started but I unable to think how to write in function.

```
  function checkTest(){
    // script and condition here that i'm stuck to begin

         alert(values);
        }


<input type="checkbox" id="st_1" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="1"> Test 1<br/> 

<input type="checkbox" id="st_2" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="2"> Test 2<br/> 

<input type="checkbox" id="st_3" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="3"> Test 3<br/>  

<input type="checkbox" id="st_4" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" value="4"> Test 4<br/> 

<input type="checkbox" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbgroup1')"> Select All <br/>

<button type="button" onclick="javascript:checkTest();" class="btn btn-default"> Enter  </button>
```

Comment: You are using javascript or you can use jQuery too?!

Comment: yup sir,as long as it give the same result. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to be correct. Had to take out the $ because they weren't working and didn't feel like troubleshooting. This will work exactly as you are requesting. Only the jQuery iteration though. Would need to change some of the aspects using Javascript.

```
    function checkTest(){
        // script and condition here that i'm stuck to begin
         var checkboxes = jQuery('.cbgroup1'), values = '';

         checkboxes.each(function(){
             if(jQuery(this).is(':checked') || jQuery('#cbgroup1_master').is(':checked')){
                 if(values != ''){
                    values += ',';
                 }
                    values += jQuery(this).val();
             }
         });
        alert(values);
    }
```

Comment: Thank @Cayce K, your code is short and dynamic,I just tested and it's working,so easily if I add anothers checkbox input,:thumb Up: :D

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether the checkbox is checked or not with the following code:

```
function checkTest(){
    // script and condition here that i'm stuck to begin
    var c1 = document.getElementById("st_1").checked;
    var c2 = document.getElementById("st_2").checked;
    var c3 = document.getElementById("st_3").checked;
    var c4 = document.getElementById("st_4").checked;
    var values = "";
    if(c1){
        //first check box is checked. you can add your desired code here
        values = values + "1";
    }
    if(c2){
        values = values + ",2";
    }
    if(c3){
        values = values + ",3";
    }
    if(c4){
        values = values + ",4";
    }

    alert(values);
}
```

Or if i misunderstood your question:

```
function checkTest(){
    // script and condition here that i'm stuck to begin
    var c1 = document.getElementById("st_1").checked;
    var c2 = document.getElementById("st_2").checked;
    var c3 = document.getElementById("st_3").checked;
    var c4 = document.getElementById("st_4").checked;
    var values = "";
    if(c1){
        //first check box is checked. you can add your desired code here
        values = values + "1";
    }
    if(c1 && c2){
        values = values + ",2";
    }
    if(c1 && c2 && c3){
        values = values + ",3";
    }
    if(c1 && c2 && c3 && c4){
        values = values + ",4";
    }

    alert(values);
}
```

EDIT: with jquery:

```
function checkTest(){
    // script and condition here that i'm stuck to begin
    var c1 = $("#st_1").prop("checked");
    var c2 = $("#st_2").prop("checked");
    var c3 = $("#st_3").prop("checked");
    var c4 = $("#st_4").prop("checked");
    var values = "";
    if(c1){
        //first check box is checked. you can add your desired code here
        values = values + "1";
    }
    if(c1 && c2){
        values = values + ",2";
    }
    if(c1 && c2 && c3){
        values = values + ",3";
    }
    if(c1 && c2 && c3 && c4){
        values = values + ",4";
    }

    alert(values);
}
```

Comment: Use a for loop. Something like `for(var i=1, r=[]; i<5; i++) if( document.getElementById('st_'+i).checked ) r[r.length]=i; return r;` which you can then use like `checkTest()+''` and produces the same result.

Comment: That's another way to do this sir.

Comment: Thank @SNt for your code,it's working actually,but I must to add  condition everytime if anothers checkbox is added :thumb up ::D

Comment: I know :)
I wrote it like to give you the idea. You can add a for loop as the first comment suggests.